# C# get position of a character from string

Tags: c#, string, position, char

My code is this:

```
 string dex = "ABCD1234";
 string ch = "C";
 string ch1, ch2;
    if (dex.Contains(ch))
    {
       string n = Convert.ToChar(dex);
       MessageBox.Show(ch + "  is on " + n + " place and is between " + ch1 + " and " + ch2);
    }
```

I wanted to convert the string into array but i can't do it and i can't retrieve the position of the 'ch' string and what's between it.

The output should be:

```
MessageBox.Show("C is on 3rd place and is between B and D");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string aS = "ABCDEFGHI";
char ch = 'C';
int idx = aS.IndexOf(ch);
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} is in position {1} and between {2} and {3}", ch.ToString(), idx + 1, aS[idx - 1], aS[idx + 1]));
```

This wont handle if your character is at position zero and some other conditions, you'll have to figure them out.

Comment: Thank you, and if i want to set instead of 'ch' a string like textbox1.text, how can i convert that into char?

Comment: Well... textbox1.Text is a full-on string property. You'd have to convert it to a character array (`Textbox1.Text.ToCharArray()`) and iterate those in a `for` loop

Answer (score 3):

You might want to [read the documentation on `System.String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its methods and properties:

The method you want is [`IndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string s = "ABCD1234" ;
char   c = 'C' ;

int offset = s.IndexOf(c) ;
bool found = index >= 0 ;
if ( !found )
{
  Console.WriteLine( "string '{0}' does not contain char '{1}'" , s , c ) ;
}
else
{
  string prefix = s.Substring(0,offset) ;
  string suffix = s.Substring(offset+1) ;

  Console.WriteLine( "char '{0}' found at offset +{1} in string '{2}'." , c , offset , s ) ;
  Console.WriteLine( "The substring before it is '{0}'."             , prefix ) ;
  Console.WriteLine( "The substring following it is '{0}'."          , suffix ) ;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Carey, but one more time, how can i search for a string from that string, instead of char 'c'. ?

Comment: As I noted in the my answer: **READ THE DOCUMENTATION.** You are not even trying to help yourself. `IndexOf()` has several *overloads* that take either `char` or `string`. Also read up on `string.IndexOfAny()` which finds the first occurrence in a string of a list of characters.)